# Xcode UITest shows green dash symbol - what does this means?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm running some UITest, the test class below shows all test are successful but the class is showing a green dash. What does this dash mean?

[image: Xcode Screenshot for a test class]

Comment: The green dash just represents a collection of tests, and all are passed. And of course If there is only one test failed, then the green dash will become red dash

Comment: testDeleteReceipts isn't a green tick, so not all tests were run, but all the ones that ran were successful.

Comment: I often see that individual text methods have the "green dash" symbol, and the test case class has the same symbol even if I run all tests, and all of them pass (Xcode 15.) I can re-run the test class, and all test methods can be marked with "green ticks," but the test class will stay a "green dash." Very confusing, and docs give no clue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-tests-and-interpreting-results.